# How can I use my current Windows 10 partition on external HDD in VMware Fusion?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, boot-camp

It is possible to use BOOTCAMP partition directly. But I want to use Windows from my external HDD directly. Is there any possible way?

Comment: What do you have in your external HDD ? A preinstalled Windows, an ISO or VHD ?

Comment: Preinstalled Windows copy. I created a USB drive with Boot Camp and installed it to my external HDD without Boot Camp.